# How do I know which NSURLRequestCachePolicy to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, caching, nsurlrequest

I want my data to be always fetched from the server except when there is no network. Then I want the cached data returned. So that whether there is network or not, my user always gets some data (instead of telling them: Not Network Connection or such). So which NSURLRequestCachePolicy should I use for that?

Comment: To answer your question - you need to use `ReturnCacheDataDontLoad` for `CachePolicy`. For more details on the cache policies please take a look at this [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/). Notice, however, what you are trying to do is more complex, than just setting `CachePolicy`.

Answer (score 4):

"I want my data to be always fetched from the server except when there is no network. Then I want the cached data returned."

The cache policy constants [are described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001695-CJBIAHGF).

None of the cache policies do what you describe. You can implement your own caching logic by serving responses out of the cache if the server is not available (this is not really recommended, however).

Your question does not describe wether you want cached responses to be persisted to disk. NSURLCache by default only caches in-memory, you can create an instance of NSURLCache that uses the disk easily:

```
  cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:[(1024*1024*512) diskCapacity:(1024*1024*1024 * 100) diskPath:@"Cache.db"]:
```

The cache can be set as the global shared URL cache, or it can be used with `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

When you decide your application should not attempt to contact the server, you can access the cache directly by [asking it for a cached response for a request](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/cachedResponseForRequest:):

```
cachedResponse = [cache cachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

The cached response is a `NSCachedURLResponse`, which contains the `NSData` and `NSURLResponse` associated with the cached representation of the response for that request. You can then give those objects to whatever methods you have implemented for handling responses from the server.

That said, using the default cache policy of `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` is almost always the best choice rather than implementing your own caching or changing the cache policy of the request. When a server responds to an HTTP request, the response includes information about how long and under what conditions the response will be valid for. For example, the response may contain a header like this:

```
Cache-control: max-age:3600
```

This is the server telling the client that the response provided will be good for 3600 seconds. `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` understands these values and the rules that govern their use on the client. If you make the same request from the client during that 3600 second period, Foundation will give your application the cached response rather than contacting the server. The server, which "owns" the data the client is requesting, is the only party that can correctly reason about the validity of responses.

So let's say that the user is "offline" during that 3600 second period in our example. If they are making that same request, the application will use the cached response. If the 3600 second period has past, the context is *expired* and *invalid*. The server has told the client that if 3600 seconds has past, it should not use this response. If the client is "offline", the client will not be able to contact the server *or* use the cache - which is exactly what you want. If the response was something that should "never" change, that the client could cache and persist forever, the server would have indicated that (in this case, possibly by sending a max-age value of years in the response).

Comment: is it universal for all servers i mean 3600 is fixed? If not then what is the average time out?